# Best way to dynamically show all keys for arrays in Python

Tags: python

I'm a newbie at Python and I'd like to know if there is a better solution for dynamically showing all the attributes under an object(keyword, woe_code, timestamp).

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
trends = models.Trends.query.all() 
for t in trends:
   print t.keyword, t.woe_id, t.woe_code, t.timestamp  #I know this is wrong, hardcoding the attributes.
```

NEW CODE:

```
trends = models.Trends.query.all() 
for t in trends:
    for k, v in vars(t).iteritems():
         print k+"KEY"
                     print v+"Value"
```

Comment: What is 'dynamically' in this case? Just print the key and value of a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__dict__`:

```
for t in trends:
    for k, v in t.__dict__.items():
        if not k.startswith('__'):
            print k, v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in dir function to get a list of the object attributes.  Something like this...

```
class T:
    g = 1
    t = 0
    b = 2

t = T()

for attribute in dir(t):    
    print "attribute %s has value %s" % (attribute,getattr(t,attribute))

"""        
--- outputs ---
attribute __doc__ has value None
attribute __module__ has value __main__
attribute b has value 2
attribute g has value 1
attribute t has value 0
"""
```